# Visual Studio localhost prompting for login

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 for a project. When I try to run the project, the browser pops up the login prompt saying Authentication Required. If I hit Ok or Cancel, it goes to the error page saying HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized.

The weird thing is the same project was working fine till today! There have been no recent web.config changes and I cannot see how any of the recent minor file changes made could cause this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which web server do you use? IIS or integrated? And how do you run your project? Press F5?

Comment: Right now trying with the Visual Studio integrated server. Tried debug (F5) and run (ctrl F5), both have same issue.

Comment: You might need admin rights to run in the debugger, depending on OS

Comment: Hey slfan, thank you very much! I had forgotten to start Visual Studio in administrator mode. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need admin rights to run in the debugger, depending on OS

Comment: sometimes we miss what's right in-front of our eyes and spend hours/days/and I even spent months trying to solve this issue where no one figured it out, until I read your answer. Simple, Obvious, and a CORRECT one. Thank you!